# Min and max value on calculator without submitting

Tags: html, calculator

So I'm working on a calculator for a school project, the idea is that you can put in numbers and it automatically produces a price. It works fine when I use sliders but I want to be able to put in your own numbers.

How can I let the calculator check the form if the didgits are past the max and min value without a submit button. Like if I set the max to 200, then you must not be able to fill in 230 for example. It works with the arrow buttons but when filling it in yourself you can fill in whatever you want.

It needs to be checked somehow but I have no idea how, take a look at the code.

```
  $(".priceslider").change(function () {

      var width = $("#width").val();
      var height = $("#height").val();
      var number = $("#number").val();

      var sale = (110 - (10 * number)) / 100;

      var pricex = ((width * height / 100) * sale) * number;

      if (pricex < 30) {
            var price = 30;
      } else {
            var price = pricex;
      }

      $("#txtWidth").text(width + ' cm');
      $("#txtHeight").text(height + ' cm');
      $("#txtNumber").text(number + ' st');
      $("#txtPrice").text('$' + price.toFixed(0));
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to manually restrict out of bounds values as shown below:

**Script:**

```
if (parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(this).attr("max"))) {
     $(this).val($(this).attr("max"));
} else if (parseInt($(this).val()) < parseInt($(this).attr("min"))) {
     $(this).val($(this).attr("min"));
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/ebb0e4qp/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the max value in the change event. If there is an overflow, remove the last number digit

```
 <body>

<div>
    <label id="lblBreedte">Breedte:</label>
    <input class="prijsslider" type="number" id="sliBreedte" value="30" min="30" max="200" />
    <label id="txtBreedte">30 cm</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label id="lblHoogte">Hoogte:</label>
    <input class="prijsslider" type="number" id="sliHoogte" value="61" min="61" max="134" />
    <label id="txtHoogte">61 cm</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label id="lblAantal">Aantal:</label>
    <input class="prijsslider" type="number" id="sliAantal" value="1" min="1" max="4" />
    <label id="txtAantal">1 st</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
    <label id="lblPrijs">Prijs:</label>
    <label id="txtPrijs">€30</label>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".prijsslider").change(function () {

      if (parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(this).attr("max"))) {

         $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, strlen($(this).val()) - 1));

      }

      var breedte = $("#sliBreedte").val();
      var hoogte = $("#sliHoogte").val();
      var aantal = $("#sliAantal").val();

      var korting = (110 - (10 * aantal)) / 100;

      var prijsx = ((breedte * hoogte / 100) * korting) * aantal;

      if (prijsx < 30) {
            var prijs = 30;
      } else {
            var prijs = prijsx;
      }

      $("#txtBreedte").text(breedte + ' cm');
      $("#txtHoogte").text(hoogte + ' cm');
      $("#txtAantal").text(aantal + ' st');
      $("#txtPrijs").text('€' + prijs.toFixed(0));
  });
</script>

</body>
```